# Make 'Page' slug the 'index'

Tags: posts, frontpage

I want to have my Index page show posts from a certain Category ('news').  I have that functionality, but is there a way I can make a 'News' Page, where the slug just points to the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take the current code you have and drop it into a page template called tpl-news.php or whatever you choose. Add the following to the header before your index.php code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: News
*/
//Add your index.php code here
//You can also use wp_redirect(home_url()) here as well if I misunderstood your question
```

Now, create a page called 'News' with a slug of 'news' and select the 'News' page template. That should do the trick for you.

I would also look at how Wordpress template hierarchy works and build template files that target a specific category - Example: category-news.php would force this file to be used  when the 'news' category permalink is viewed rather than the default archive template.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy